# How to say aether not to fail for dependencies which are not in repository?

Tags: java, maven, aether

I'm trying to collect dependencies of artifacts using [eclipse-aether](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.aether/aether-api/1.0.0.v20140518), doing the following:

```java
Artifact artifact = ...
DependencyVisitor dependencySaver = ...

ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
descriptorRequest.setArtifact(artifact);
descriptorRequest.setRepositories(Booter.newRepositories(system, session));
ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor(session, descriptorRequest);

CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
collectRequest.setRootArtifact(descriptorResult.getArtifact());
collectRequest.setDependencies(descriptorResult.getDependencies());
collectRequest.setManagedDependencies(descriptorResult.getManagedDependencies());
collectRequest.setRepositories(descriptorRequest.getRepositories());
CollectResult collectResult = system.collectDependencies(session, collectRequest);

collectResult.getRoot().accept(dependencySaver);
```

[Apache](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases) repository happens to contain artifacts with dependencies, which themselves are not in repository. For example, [org.apache.deltaspike:parent-code:pom:1.1.0](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/deltaspike/parent-code/1.1.0/parent-code-1.1.0.pom) has dependency on `org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.2.Final`, which is not present.

In such situations Aether rejects to report results:

```java
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.deltaspike:parent-code:pom:1.1.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
    at xxxxxxx.DependencyScanner$NodeScanner.run(DependencyScanner.java:128)
    at xxxxxxx.InsistentExecutor$Slave$ActionRunnable.run(InsistentExecutor.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.2.Final in apache (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:966)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:368)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:359)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:355)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.2.Final in apache (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:pom:1.0.2.Final in apache (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
... 17 more
```

Is there a way to make aether give at least partial result with names of all accessible dependencies?

Comment: I may have missed something but this doesn't make sense: you need to download the POM to resolve the transitive dependencies. If the artifact doesn't exist, how can you resolve the transitive dependencies? But this artifact exists in Maven Central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.0.2.Final/

Comment: @Tunaki, in this situation I prefer to ignore unaccessible transitive dependencies. Edited question

Comment: @Tunaki, I looked into another index of that repository, where it doesn't exist: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/. That's strange :)  But anyway, it seems to fail when resolving that arquilian-bom artifact

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't see a way to ignore this... I was pointing at Maven Central in my previous comment, which is different than the Apache repo (which indeed doesn't contain the artifact `arquillian-bom`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that the given artifact:

org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.0

contains the wrong version. The version must be:

[org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.0.Final](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.arquillian%7Carquillian-bom%7C1.1.0.Final%7Cpom)

You need to define the version correctly:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, that artifact actually depends on version 1.0.2.Final, not 1.1.0 as was written before. So version is correct. I've edited question

Comment: This does not change anything: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.arquillian%7Carquillian-bom%7C1.0.2.Final%7Cpom